# Google map custom marker direction point

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I have searched a lot and wasn't able to find a solution, at least not the one that would satisfy my needs.

In the android application, I have an activity with google map and I need to place a custom current location marker that rotates to point the direction a user (device) is looking at (portrait mode)? Google maps and Uber application do this very nicely but I am not sure which way to do this,

1. Is it accomplished using sensors in the phone like accelerometer and magnetometer or there are multiple (better) ways to achieve this?
2. What is the correct way to accomplish smooth animation like the one in example applications?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a feature request in Google Maps Platform Public Issue Tracker for adding a bearing / heading in Directions API to reflect what angle the user is looking at. You can check it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/35824456

Comment: Sorry that link is not related to what I asked.